# populating a dictionary of objects, from objects written separately in a file C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, readfile, writefile

I made an example program in order to get this going so I can actualy learn how to use it and aply it in my actual project.
In brief, my first try was writting the Person instance into the file, but I couldnt populate later a list with the different instances written (I only could see the first written, and the list had only 1 element). So I came up with saving the Person instance into a dictionary, writting the dictionary into the file, and then reading complete dictionary from file before adding a new element (Person instance), but I couldnt accomplish this either.

Let's say a I have a class `Person`

```
[Serializable]
public class  Person
{
    public string name, lname;
    public int age;

    public void newperson(string name,
              string lname,
              int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

in my main class I have two methods (honestly stolen from here, thanks @Daniel Schroeder @deadlydog) to write and read from file, through binary format.

```
    Person nper = new Person(); //nper, an instance of Person
    Dictionary<string, Person> dict = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
    const string file = @"..\..\data.bin";
```

_

```
public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
        }
    }
```

_

```
public static T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

I kind of understand this methods, but, I would be unable to code/modify them, it exceeds my knowledge.

In order to test writting/reading I dragged a few textboxes and a `button1`

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //saving textboxes to Person instance 
        nper.newperson(textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text, Convert.ToInt16(textBox6.Text));

        //saving that object into a dictionary<string,Person> the key is the name, the object is the Person itself
        dict[nper.name] = nper;

        //Writting this dict
        WriteToBinaryFile(file, dict, true);
    }
```

Then, I dragged a few more separated textboxes to check the reading:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //read the file and save all into dict (is this working like I think it should? is dict, getting all the data from file?)
            dict = ReadFromBinaryFile<Dictionary<string,Person>>(file);


            //write into diferent textboxes the Person properties, for the key that matches with another text box that i fill manually to check
            textBox1.Text = dict[tbSearch.Text].name;
            textBox2.Text = dict[tbSearch.Text].lname;
            textBox3.Text = dict[tbSearch.Text].age.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
```

in `button2_Click` **is `dict` getting all the data from file?**

edit: Try and result:
Let's say I fill the initial boxes with
John,
Doe,
40
click `button1` 
then load another one,
Clark,
Kent,
50

If I write "John" in `tbSearch` I see full data of John (name, lastname and age)
If I fill with "Clark" I get a dictionary error "the key given was not present in the dictionary"

Comment: Yes. Whats your try result?

Comment: Set append parameter = false in WriteToBinaryFile(file, dict, false). May be binaryformatter read first section (first button1 click). I have not editor to ensure that.

Comment: damn, how could I overlook that. My mistake, it worked. Thanks @RezaArabQaeni !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set append parameter = false in `WriteToBinaryFile(file, dict, false)`.

When first call of WriteToBinaryFile method executed BinaryFormatter write dictionary with one element, In second try write a dictionary with two element but appended to first write, So BinaryFormatter when try deserialize stream, read first section contains save dictionary with one key in first try (first button1 click).

Comment: Sorry, Reza, I didn't understand the last part "BinaryFormatter read first section contains save dictionary with one key in first try (first button1 click)." But I'm getting an error when the file is created for the first time or it exist but it is empty, I think you were trying to explain that. Thanks.